# Getting Field by name from feature using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr, .net

I have recently started using GDAL in C#, I want to get a value from a field of a feature using the name of that field. In the docs [here](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRFeature.html) it says that the operator `[char*]` is supported, however it's not in the .net package.

Here is my code

```
 Feature feature = layer.GetNextFeature();
 var field = feature['myField']; // not recognized :(
```

Is there a way to get a value by field name from the feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround there are some functions in order to get a typed value by name. In my case I'm using `feature.GetFieldAsString("myField")`